# NoMethodError: undefined method `setup' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationsController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

Searching for this problem has only turned up issues with specific gems or classes that other people have dealt with. In my case, I think there's something wrong with rspec in general.

Whenever I generate a controler with `rails generate ControllerName`, it sets everything up and things seem to work fine. I've routed a few controllers and tested them in development and production and everything works.

The only thing that seems to be broken is testing them with rspec. Right now I have two controllers in my project, and whenever I run rspec/spec, most specs generated by `rails g` turns up this error:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `setup' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::MoreStuffHere
```

For example, I have a WelcomeController and ApplicationsController and these are the errors I keep getting:

```
undefined method `setup' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationsController:Class
undefined method `setup' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::WelcomeController:Class
undefined method `setup' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::WelcomeAboutHtmlErb:Class
undefined method `setup' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::WelcomeIndexHtmlErb:Class
```

Interestingly, I don't get errors for their `helper_spec`'s

Here is a full error in case this helps:

`An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/applications_controller_spec.rb.`

```
Failure/Error:
  RSpec.describe ApplicationsController, type: :controller do

  end

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `setup' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationsController:Class
# ./spec/controllers/applications_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Does anyone have any idea where this issue could lie?

Comment: any news on this one? :/

Comment: My answer below doesn't solve the problem for you?

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `spec_helper.rb` I had

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # More code here.
end
```

All I had to do was add `require 'rspec/rails'` under `require 'rails/all'`. This solved my problem.

Yet, I don't know why. If someone can elaborate that would be great. I already had `require 'rspec/rails'` in `rails_herlper.rb`, but obviously that wasn't good enough.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the solution here is somewhat what Damian Rivas says there, but the important thing is:

- in rails helper you have a line:

`require 'spec_helper'`

- in spec_helper you have in config block line to include devise helpers:

`config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller`

- you also as said above have to have `rspec/rails` require line

The main point there was that you have to watch the order here... always including `rspec/rails` has to go before `spec_helper`

So lets say example `spec_helper.rb` looks like:

```
require 'rubygems'

Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

Then our `rails_hepler.rb` has to look like:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)
abort('The Rails environment is running in production mode!') if Rails.env.production?

require 'rspec/rails'
require 'spec_helper'
```

Then in `sample_spec.rb` you require `rails_helper`, or in my case I require through `.rspec` so I don't have to have it on top of every spec.

Hope it helps somebody :)